# Cómo utilizar mi middleware para que funcione con más de un parámetro

Tags: laravel, controller, middleware

He creado el middleware **UsertypeMiddleware** en Laravel 8, para restringir a los usuarios según su tipo de usuario (cree la columna "type" en mi tabla users), y contiene la siguiente función handle:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $type)
{
    if($request->user()->type <> $type){
        return redirect()
            ->route('main')
            ->withErrors('¡No tienes acceso a este recurso!');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Al cual lo llamé **'usertype'** en protected $routeMiddleware, y lo utilizo en mi controlador de la siguiente forma:

```
public function __construct() {

    $this->middleware(['auth','verified','usertype:1']);

}
```

Donde el usuario 1 es administrador total, el 2 administrador de algunos recursos, etc.

Todo funciona correctamente, pero mi pregunta es, cómo puedo agregar más de un tipo de usuario, sin tener que crear un middleware para cada grupo de usuarios. Por ejemplo para que el usuario de tipo 1 y el de tipo 2 puedan usar los recursos de mi controlador:

```
$this->middleware(['auth','verified','usertype:1,2']);
```

Espero haberme explicado.

Comment: Si le pasas `1,2` como muestras en el ejemplo `usertype:1,2`, ¿que recibes en el middleware? ¿un string con valor `1,2`?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ  voy a revisar, pero en lo funcional, me permite el usuario 1 y el 2 lo ignora.

Comment: sí, cuando le pongo `1,2` devuelve solo "1" @porloscerrosΨ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logré solucionarlo poniéndole `...` antes de $type para que reciba array, lo cual me devolvía:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "1"
  1 => "2"
]
```

y mandando los datos de la misma forma en el controlador (`usertype:1,2`), modifiqué el if de la siguiente manera:

```
if(in_array($request->user()->type, $type)==false)
```

Para ver si el usuario contenía uno de los tipos permitidos. Función final:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$type){
        if(in_array($request->user()->type, $type)==false){
            return redirect()
                ->route('main')
                ->withErrors('¡No tienes acceso a este recurso!');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Por si a alguien le sirve. Si tienes alguna sugerencia, por favor comenta.

Comment: Ohh... estaba escribiendo otra respuesta parecida al mismo tiempo que tú. También las dejo ahí pues tiene una pequeña diferencia, y puede servir a alguien más.

Comment: Sí, justo la vi después de lograrlo! Tenía conocimiento de los tres puntitos, pero no se me había ocurrido ayer como ocuparlo. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: Muy buena solución. Como una mejora te recomendaría usar el operador ! para la evaluación dentro de la condición, así: if(!in_array($request->user()->type, $type))

Comment: Gracias @MaríaPaulina, menos código.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando al middleware le pasas sólo un argumento, para el caso:

```
$this->middleware(['usertype:1']);
```

No tendrás problema en tomarlo de la variable en que la función asigna el valor de ese argumento:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $type)
{
    // aquí $type valdrá 1
}
```

Pero cuando al middleware le pasas una cantidad `n` de argumentos separados por `,` (coma):

```
$this->middleware(['usertype:1,2']);
```

La función del middleware, asignará cada valor separado por coma a un argumento distinto, por lo que tendrías que hacer algo así:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $type1, $type2)
{
    // aquí $type1 valdrá 1
    // y $type2 valdrá 2
}
```

Pero claro, **no** sabes de antemano cuántos argumentos tendrá la función, pues dependerá de a cuántos tipos de usuarios quieres darle permiso en cada caso.

Para resolverlo, puedes usar el spĺat operator `...` Ref: [Listas de argumentos de longitud variable](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)

> PHP tiene soporte para listas de argumentos de longitud variable en funciones definidas por el usuario. Esto se implementa utilizando el token `...`

Entonces, para aplicarlo, puedes definir tu función de esta manera:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$types)
{
    // aquí $types será un array 
    // con la cantidad de elementos que le pases (separados por coma) al middleware.
    // si le pasas usertype:1  el array será array ( 0 => '1', )
    // si le pasas usertype:1,2  el array será array ( 0 => '1', 1 => '2', )
}
```

Bien, con eso ya resuelves cómo recibir todos los valores que le pasas al middleware.
Pero entonces las cosas cambian dentro de la función, pues vas a tener un array de valores en vez de un único valor, por lo tanto tendrás que adaptar la lógica a eso.
Por ejemplo, iterando sobre los argumentos con un `foreach`:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$types)
{
    foreach($types as $type) {
        if((int) $request->user()->type === (int) $type)
            return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect()
        ->route('main')
        ->withErrors('¡No tienes acceso a este recurso!');
}
```